# Require in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have the following ruby code:

```
require 'locationclass'
```

I have installed the gem locationclass, but it's still giving me the error message:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- locationclass
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from C:/Ruby/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Where do you see this error? In ```irb``` or somewhere else?

Comment: Also could you provide a link to ```locationclass``` gem repo?
Sometimes their main files called differently than gem itself.

Comment: I saw the error in irb and a ruby program. `locationclass` is on rubygems, at [link](https://rubygems.org/gems/locationclass).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` command loads files, not gems. As I see the gem "locationclass" has only one file in its `lib` folder, named `main.rb`. So to load it you need to call:

```
require 'main'
```

Also, it's a bad style to have different names for gem and its main file. Not to mention that name 'main' is too generic.

Comment: @Anonymous version `1.0.0` was released yesterday and the file is now `locationclass.rb` all that being said I have to assume you designed this gem because otherwise I would not recommend using a gem that went from `0.0.0` to `1.0.0` in 2 days